# Is it discouraged to @user notify the OP in an answer?

Tags: discussion

Looking around the site it looks like answers don't include an @user notification like some comments do. Is this actively discouraged? I can't find any relevant discussion in the help.

Comment: It can be useful if there are multiple participants already and a commenter wants to make it clear that they're addressing the OP about something specifically. Otherwise, it's just *unnecessary*, but not really *discouraged*

Comment: To add to Makoto's answer, we discourage salutations in answers addressed to the question author. Answers should be written for a broad audience: while they should fix the issue at hand, they should be useful for anyone who reads the page subsequently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The asker (e.g. OP) is notified whenever an answer appears on their question, so...using @ to get their attention is redundant.

@ will only work in comments, and only if that person has commented that you're trying to reach out to, so meta-annotations like @downvoter won't work.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize @user didn't even work in an answer. I guess this question is moot then. Thanks!

Comment: I believe they can work in chat too, but I'm not sure how relevant that is here.

Answer (score 2):

Putting @user in an answer does not notify the user. However, it can still be appropriate to mention specific users in an answer for reasons other than trying to get their attention.

When you incorporate something in your answer that was written by another user in a comment, or in another answer to the same question, or in a related question, or when you use a library written by a site user, etc, it's good style to give attribution to that user.

For example: "to expand on the [other answer by @JaneDoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52345272/) about using `foo`: in edge case X you need to use `bar`". Adding a link is of course also a good method for attribution, and an @ is not strictly necessary to know that you are talking about a user, but it helps to signal that you are indeed mentioning someone on SE.

This could add to a sense of community, which might be undesired when it is making the answer less general or less useful for a general audience, but that is not the case in most of these situations. And it may actually serve to parse a sentence for usernames that could introduce ambiguity, for example "the answer by a pink unicorn" vs "the answer by @a pink unicorn" or "this is useful, as i am social distancing mentioned" vs "this is useful, as @i am social distancing mentioned".

Comment: Leave off the @ and you still have a perfectly attributed response.  Adding Stack Overflow's own syntactic sugar into that debate isn't desirable IMO.

Comment: Do not use @ signs to refer to users in posts. My name does not contain an @ sign.

Comment: @CodyGray despite the fact that your name does not contain an @ sign it may still be useful to add the @ in a post, as I tried to argue in my answer: 1. it helps to signal that you are talking about an SE user 2. it adds to a sense of community and 3. it helps to disambiguate sentences with weird user names. If you think these reasons are invalid or very minor then maybe you can elaborate a little?

Comment: (1) Using my name is sufficient signal, as in any normal conversation. (2) There's nothing communal about an at-sign. It is decidedly the opposite of communal, as it is not how you customarily refer to people. (Twitter is not real life.) (3) No disambiguation is required in normal prose. If you are concerned there might be some discrepancy, say something like, "As the user a pink unicorn mentioned in their answer...". Better yet, turn the words into a link, which will remove any potential ambiguity.